# Help with combining two queries into one

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have two tables, `s` and `c`.

This query works for the inner join

```
select s.cname, c.HName 
from c inner join s on (c.pid = s.pid AND c.cid = s.cid)
```

I'm having trouble with a where clause. There's a flag in table `c` indicating an error, and I want to display only the names where the error flag is set to 'Y', but it also has to be the most recent entry (checks every hour so many many entries).

So far I have this:

```
select max(date),cid,pid, case WHEN error_flag='Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Still has Error"
from c
group by cid,pid,error_flag
```

That query does the job, but I need to essentially make a where clause for the first query that achieves the same thing. Any suggestions?

Note: Using SQL server 2016

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first query has error_flag and date in one of the tables then something like this would probably work:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY s.Date DESC ) AS Rownum ,
       s.cname ,
       c.HName
FROM   c
       INNER JOIN s ON (   c.pid = s.pid
                           AND c.cid = s.cid )
WHERE s.error_Flag = 'Y' AND Rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Please take the time to use the formatting tools above the box where you answer - you get a preview before you post to check!

Comment: Also - I believe you would get the error `Invalid column name 'rownum'.` with this. You can't use aliases from the `SELECT` list of a query in that query's `WHERE` clause - nor, for that matter, can you use a windowing function in the `WHERE` clause (unless it's embedded in a subquery, where it cant be used in the sub-query's `WHERE` clause, etc.)

Comment: You're correct, can't use alias "rownum" in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need a windowing function to achieve this.

Would something like this give you the correct results?

```
select s.scname, cTable.HName, cTable.error_flag AS [Still has Error]
from s inner join 
    (select top 1 c.[date] as error_date, c.cid, c.pid, c.HName, c.error_flag 
        from c 
        order by c.[date] desc) cTable 
on cTable=s.pid and c_table.cid = s.cid
where cTable.error_flag = 'Y'
```